# How to make-up/redesign/change-all-functions-and-variable-names of a program

Tags: c++

I have a program in C/C++ code, and I wonder what approaches/programs/methodologies can be used to:

- change automatically or following some rules
  a) all variable and function names of the program
  b) redesign it completely: change indentation, order of how functions appear on the code, etc

So at the end, the program compiles again and gives exactly the same results.

Thankss

Comment: Does this sound to me a way to present an application that's not written by you to be yours? :(

Answer (score 2):

[Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/), even tho it's not free software. Also assuming, you work with MS-IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for an obfuscator for C++ code.

A quick googling provides these twos examples of such:

- http://freshmeat.net/projects/cxx-obfus
- http://www.stunnix.com/prod/cxxo/overview.shtml

Others almost certainly exist as well.

Answer (score 0):

Without good unit tests it's very hard to be sure that you get exactly the same results.

It's tempting to use simple text manipulation scripting tools (such as perl ) however thse don't understand the C++ syntax and so you get into confusions such literal strings versus variable names.

Hence seek out refactoring tools such as [this](http://www.ifs.hsr.ch/Projects/Projects/C_Refactoring)

As has already been observed, if you want obfuscation then there are dedicated tools for that.

Comment: Obfuscation tools referenced by Dav

Answer (score 0):

I like ad-hoc perl using regular expressions.  I've blogged a couple examples of such changes:

http://peeterjoot.wordpress.com/2009/09/02/regular-expression-driven-code-alteration/

http://peeterjoot.wordpress.com/2009/08/06/dirty-perl-tricks-using-evaluations-in-a-replacement-expression/